# How do I list absolutely all of the extensions, addons, plugins, etc currently installed in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, browser-addons

How can I get a list of every single extension and addon that's been added my Firefox installation?

I recently discovered that many "search engine" addons are missing from `about:addon` and that you have to dig into `about:support` to see them :/

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1267206

I also recently discovered that mozilla allows you to define [Native Messaging Hosts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Native_messaging) (local apps on your machine that integrate with websites via json messages being passed-between the browser and the backend app). I'm not sure if those are visible in `about:addon` or `about:support`.

I also know there's a concept of [themes](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/themes/) and [plugins](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/open-h264-plugin-firefox), both of which can be added to Firefox.

Are there any more names for `<type of thing that can be added to firefox>`? How do I enumerate absolutely **all of them**?

Answer (score 2):

On a Windows OS machine, Nirsoft's [BrowserAddonsView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/web_browser_addons_view.html) does a good job showing all extensions and plugins for almost all browsers, including Firefox.

Though I've not tried doing so, it *might* run under [wine](https://www.winehq.org/) in Linux. [It's amazing how much Windows software runs well under wine!]